# I am facing error when using scala eclipse maven GUI

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am facing error while using scala project in eclipse and maven, This is the project which I build from scratch ,  and it was working fine at that time.But now when I open it after a month it does show errors as shown in screenshots, even if i do mvn package it generates jar file as expected , But I see all my class files showing error at each line as shown in screen shot, what may be the problem?[image]

I am using scala version: 2.10.6 and attached is below pom file.
scala.ide.org :
provider : scala-ide.org 
plugin-name : scala2.10 jar
version ; 4.4.1201605041056
pligin-id: org.scala-ide.scala210.jars

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.blogspot.whileonefork</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvn-scala-trial1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Sample Project for Blog</name>
  <url>http://com.blogspot.whileonefork</url>

    <properties>
        <spark.version>1.6.0</spark.version>
    </properties>

  <!-- Notify Maven it can download things from here -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>  

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala</id>
            <name>Scala Tools</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Scala version is very important. Luckily the plugin warns you if you don't specify: 
        [WARNING] you don't define org.scala-lang:scala-library as a dependency of the project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPARK CSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>  
    <!-- add the maven-scala-plugin to the toolchain -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- adding here -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.asharma.mainjob.main_job</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <!-- This plugin creates a single jar with all 
                   the dependencies that are not already supplied by
                   the Spark runtime (scope 'provided'). -->
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>             
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.frugalmechanic</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-optparse</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.scala-tools
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-scala-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.15.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                    <forkMode>pertest</forkMode> 
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m</argLine>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore> 
                    <skip>false</skip> 
                    <includes> 
                     <include>**/*IntegrationTestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>       
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: you shoul add you pom.xml and also specify what scala version you're trying to use and what's the eclipse version

Comment: What version of http://scala-ide.org/ ?

Comment: edited the question.